# Common Lisp Loop macro variable bindings

Tags: loops, common-lisp

I am having a problem in understanding how the `with` keyword works. In particular, I considered it to be same as a `let` statement but it does not follow.

For example, these two codes "should" print the same values but the first one gives `(nil nil)` while the latter works fine.

```
(loop for c in clauses
    with p = (car c)
    collect p)

(loop for c in clauses
    collect (car c))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`with` is to create local auxiliary variables. They are initialized **once before the loop started** and thus would be identical to writing this:

```
(let ((p (car c))
  (loop for c in clauses
    collect p))
```

Except the fact that it seems `c` exists as `nil` at the same time `(car c)` i sdone. I think it's because `loop` creates all their variables in one go at the beginning like I created `p` here.

You are looking for `for`:

```
(loop 
  for c in clauses
  for p = (car c)
  collect p)
```

Why not do it with destructuring?:

```
(loop 
  for (p) in clauses
  collect p)
```

Comment: The `for` … `=` clause executes each time when no `then` is given; you do not need to repeat the form.

Comment: @Svante That makes sense. I try to avoid using `=` since while you can do everything with it it is never the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

One thing which helps to understand `LOOP` a bit better is that a `LOOP` has three different clause sections

```
(loop

  ; first a single optional NAME clause

  ; then zero or more variable clauses with WITH, INITIAL, FINALLY and/or FOR

  ; then zero or more main clauses with DO, RETURN, COLLECT, APPEND, SUM, NCONC, ...
  )
```

One has to keep the order of these clause sections.

There are two ways to introduce variables: `FOR` and `WITH`. `FOR` updates the variable in each iteration and `WITH` will do it only once. You can write these clauses in any order within the correct section, but generally the `WITH` binding and its value will be created before the `FOR` variable will have a correct value - though not always.

LispWorks warns about your specific code:

```
CL-USER 6 > (loop for c in '((1) (2) (3))
                  with p = (car c)
                  collect p)

Warning: Local Variable Initialization clause
  (the binding of P) follows iteration forms but will be evaluated before them.

(NIL NIL NIL)
```

Often

```
(loop for c in clauses
    with p = (car c)
    collect p)
```

will be implemented by something like this:

```
(...
   (let ((c nil) ...)
     (let ((p (car c)))   ; your (CAR ...)  form

        ; iteration code ...

     )))
```

In this case you had some 'luck', since `(car nil)` happens to work and only the result is not what you expect - silently.

But this will create an error:

```
(loop for c in '((1) (2) (3))
      with p = (1+ c)    ; note the 1+ instead of CAR
      collect p)
```

Here `(1+ nil)` won't work and will be an error, because the function `1+` accepts only numbers as arguments. You won't see an unexpected result, but an error.

**Style Rules**

- Don't mix `FOR` and `WITH` clauses.
- Write `WITH` clauses before `FOR` clauses.
- Don't depend on implementation specific behaviour and effects.